# How to query elasticsearch for greater than and less than?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get values between 1000 and 2000. I tried this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "gte": 1000
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "lte": 2000
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't give satisfactory results. Greater than works fine. I am using elasticsearch v6.3. Please help with solution for both inclusive and exclusive of both values.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Returns documents where the `price` value between 1000 and 2000 inclusive.

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "price" : {
                "gte" : 1000,
                "lte" : 2000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Range Query**
>
> Matches documents with fields that have terms within a certain range.
>   The type of the Lucene query depends on the field type, for string
>   fields, the TermRangeQuery, while for number/date fields, the query is
>   a NumericRangeQuery.

`gte` - Greater-than or equal to

`lte` - Less-than or equal to

`gt` - Greater-than

`lt` - Less-than

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: doesn't it require the `bool` and `filter` key?

Comment: No it doesn't for ES 6.3. Take a look at example given in the link.

Comment: As per your example with `bool` and `filter` you can merge `gte` and `lte` within a single `price` bracket, should work similar.