# Run a subquery for each of the filtered elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk

I have an index named employees with the following structure:

```
{
id: integer,
name: text,
age: integer,
cityId: integer,
resumeText: text           <--------- parsed resume text
}
```

I want to search employees with certain criteria e.g having age > 40, resumeText contains a specific skill or employee belongs to a certain city etc, and have the following query for so far requirement:

```
{
query:{
bool:{
should:[
{
term:{
cityId:2990
},
{
match:{
resumeText:"marketing"
},
{
match:{
resumeText:"critical thinking"
}}}
],
filter:{
range:{
age:{
gte:40
}}}}}
}
```

This gives me expected results but i want to know also among the returned documents/employees which are the ones whose resumeText contains the mentioned skills. e.g in the response, I want to get documents having mentioned that this document had matched "critical thinking" , this employee had matched both the skills and this employee didn't match any skills (as it was returned based on other filters)

What changes do i need to do to get the desired results:

- can aggregation help?
- can we rum a script for EACH filtered document to compute desired result (sub query for each document)?
- any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use aggregation.

[Refer this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation)

You can bucket like how many resumes are matching each skill you are looking for.

```
GET employees/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "marketing_resume_count" :   { "match" : { "resumeText" : "marketing"   }},
          "thinking_resume_count" : { "match" : { "resumeText" : "thinking" }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To extend to your use case:

You can add `query` section to the query as below

```
GET employees/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query":{
        "match":{
           "region":"AM"
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "messages" : {
          "filters" : {
            "filters" : {
              "marketing_resume_count" :   { "match" : { "resumeText" : "marketing"   }},
              "thinking_resume_count" : { "match" : { "resumeText" : "thinking" }}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

You can use `range` query to handle `gte` and `let` conditions. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325857/how-to-query-elasticsearch-for-greater-than-and-less-than) for range query example. This can be used in place of `query` section.

Comment: thanks @Gibbs, this query gives me aggregation on parent level of filters, I cannot map this info to each matching document, it gives general count like `marketing_resume_count:{ "doc_count" : 2 }` across all matching docs, where i want to know which document(s) in particular have matched this search also, can we do that? or can we add the matching doc Ids to above query?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using [TopHits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation)